# Fetch specific website'SSL certificate's public key on shared server

Tags: openssl

I have several websites hosted on the same server. Each of them has its own SSL certificate.
I want to retrieve the public key from a specific website's certificate using this command `openssl s_client -connect url:port` but it returns the last SSL certificate installed on the server and not the one that I want.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the domain name for the server you want to access using the `-servername` option to `s_client`